# select numbers from text with preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

i couldnt find the idea to do what i want

so i decided to ask my question here :)

i want select numbers of groups from text with preg_match_all

```
(itemgroup (index 24813) (group (200 24813)))
(itemgroup (index 2481) (group (50 2461)(100 2471)(150 2491)))
```

i want the output to be like that

```
index 24813 => 24813

index 2481 => 2461 / 2471 / 2491
```

is there any idea how to do it with preg_match_all

Thank You

Comment: Do the number have to contain 4 characters?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
<?php
$string = '
(itemgroup (index 24813) (group (200 24813)))
(itemgroup (index 2481) (group (50 2461)(100 2471)(150 2491)))
';

preg_match_all('#\(itemgroup \(index ([0-9]+)\) \(group ([0-9()\s]+)\)\n*#', $string, $match);
$index = $match[1];
$groups = $match[2];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($index); ++$i) {
    preg_match_all('#\([0-9]+ ([0-9]+)\)#', $groups[$i], $group);
    $group = implode(' / ', $group[1]);
    echo 'index ' . $index[$i] . ' => ' . $group . "\n";
}
```

Comment: wow, that what i wanted exactly, thank you very much sir , your awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

i am trying now to select the numbers from Arcs the middle one if there is 3 numbers in this

arcs and the last one of there is 2 numbers in arcs

for example (100 24715) output should be : 24715

(150 2491 58) output should be : 2491

i tried

```
<?php

 $string = '((50 24610 0)(100 24715)(150 2491 58))';

         preg_match_all('/\s*\(\s*[0-9]+\s*?([0-9]\d+)+\s*?[0-9]+\s*\)/',
 $string, $matches);

         $matches = implode(' & ', $matches[1]);

         echo $matches . "<br>"; 

?>
```

output

```
24610 & 2471 & 2491
```

output should be

```
24610 & 24715 & 2491
```

i dont know why it dont display number 5 in middle number